# What is the best way of saving related model in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model named Company:

```
class Company(TimeStampedModel):
     company_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
     legal_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     trading_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

     # address
     address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
     city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
     state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
     zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

     # contact details
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
     phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

And other model is CompanyAttributes:

```
class CompanyAttributes(TimeStampedModel):
""" All attributes of company"""

    corporate = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.TextField(max_length=100)
```

For a particular company I can have many attributes like billing address, CIN , GSTIN , Account number
I displayed all the fields in a Single form by defining all the fields as form fields now I want to save all of them in one go . One way is overriding the save_model of ModelAdmin and save each attribute one by one. 
Is there a way by using save_related or some other method so that I can save all in one go.

My model

```
class CompanyModelForm(ModelForm):
    pan_number = CharField()
    cin_number = CharField()
    gstin_number = CharField()
    account_number = CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CorporateModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['zipcode'].required = True
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['phone'].required = True
        self.fields['cin_number'].required = True
        self.fields['gstin_number'].required = True

        obj = kwargs.get('instance')
        if obj:
           self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled' 

class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CompanyModelForm
    search_fields = ['company_id', 'legal_name', 'trading_name', 'address','city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'email', 'phone']
    list_display = ['id', 'legal_name', 'trading_name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'email', 'phone']
    readonly_fields = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`InlineModelAdmin` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

This will do it for you.

```
class CompanyAttributesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CompanyAttributes

class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = (CompanyAttributesInline,)
```